# Use Meld instead of Kompare in KdeSVN

Tags: svn, diff, meld

i tried using Meld as external diff in KdeSVN as `meld -on -` (settings>configure kdesvn>diff&merge) but Meld complains that the usage is wrong:

```
meld: error: no such option: -o

Finished
Usage: 
  meld                        Start with an empty window
  meld <file|dir>             Start a version control comparison
  meld <file> <file> [<file>] Start a 2- or 3-way file comparison
  meld <dir> <dir> [<dir>]    Start a 2- or 3-way directory comparison
  meld <file> <dir>           Start a comparison between file and dir/file
```

i have no idea what parameters that i should use, could someone give me the correct command?

Comment: i tried `meld %f %f` but -as expected- it compares the selected file to itself.

Comment: How to get this working in the year 2020? When I right-click a file and "diff with head", it diffs the entire tree, and shows all changes files, then I have to select my individual file. Since I just right-clicked that file, I would expect to diff only one file, without the intervening step

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The right solution for this problem is:
meld %1 %2

Comment: `%1` and `%2` don't appear to be valid operators as Meld simply tries to open those strings as files. Perhaps kdesvn has changed the parameter types?

Answer (score 2):

I was experiencing a similar problem after altering this setting.

In the history-window, I was double-clicking on the modified files in the bottom-right-hand pane, assuming that would give me the diff.

Instead, kdesvn opened a window containing the text of the file.

I've now realised my mistake:

- double-clicking = "annotate" action

In order to diff, you need to **right-click** the file, and select "**Diff previous**" in the context menu.

Thought I'd better share, in-case anyone else new to kdesvn makes the same wrong assumption.